# Lightning model popup not appering correctly when opend with lightning quick action

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, aura

Lightning Component:

```
<aura:component implements="force:lightningQuickActionWithoutHeader,force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId" access="global" >      
<aura:attribute name="recordId" type="String" />
        <header class="slds-modal__header">
        <h2 id="modal-heading-01" class="slds-modal__title slds-hyphenate">Cancel Order</h2>
      </header>
      <div class="slds-modal__content slds-p-around_medium" id="modal-content-id-1">
        <p>Are you sure you want to cancel this order?</p>
      </div>
      <footer class="slds-modal__footer">          
        <lightning:button name='No' label='No' />
        <lightning:button variant="brand" name='Yes' label='Yes'/>
      </footer>
</aura:component>
```

[image]

I wanted to show my model pop like
[image]

Comment: Your HTML is wrong,  get a whole HTML block from here https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/modals/#site-main-content as per your requirement

Comment: Have you tried changing text from h2 and div?

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way is to remove the modal and use a `lightning:card` instead.
try this code

```
<aura:component>
    <lightning:card title="Cancel Order">        
        <p class="slds-p-horizontal_small">
           Are you sure you want to cancel this order?
        </p>
          <aura:set attribute="footer">
             <lightning:button name='No' label='No' />
             <lightning:button variant="brand" name='Yes' label='Yes'/>
        </aura:set>
    </lightning:card>
</aura:component>
```

Answer (score 0):

add this to your aura cmp.

```
 <aura:html tag="style">
    .cuf-content {
        padding: 0 0rem !important;
    }
    .slds-p-around--medium {
        padding: 0rem !important;
    }       
    .slds-modal__content{
        overflow-y:hidden !important;
        height:unset !important;
        max-height:unset !important;
    }
</aura:html>
```